# Hover Effect,Jquery,what is the error in this jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi Friends
i was using the following jquery,but it is not gaving an output what is the error in the code?

```
$('.event').hover(function() {
  $('.popupbox1').show();
  $('.popupbox1').css({position:'absolute',top: $(this).offset().top - 15 +'px',left: $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() +25 +'px',zIndex:1000});
,function() {
  $('.popupbox1').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant markup?  You could create a live demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Try firebug extension for firefox. It will tell you exactly where your error is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a missing `}` and the 'px' entries were unnecessary.  Give this a shot:

```
$('.event').hover(
  function() {
    $('.popupbox1').show();
    $('.popupbox1').css({position:'absolute',
                         top: $(this).offset().top - 15,
                         left: $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() + 25,
                         zIndex:1000
                       });
  },
  function() {
    $('.popupbox1').hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: @Alex it really helps to format things better.  In it's original form, the missing `}` would be a lot harder to locate.

Comment: Fosco: actually it is a output from php,so that make it harder to format,thks for let me know where was the error ;)